# Game Server Mechanic

Tags: java, libgdx, server, client-server

Hey guys :) Im currently developing a little rpg duengon crawler.
I really want to implement a local and an online multiplayer function, i know how servers are working and how to make them using sockets or kryonet.

But heres my question, i want that when someone, starts a local server in my game, that it starts an runnable jar file which includes the server, is that recommend or just stupid ? Should the server be included in the game or outside in an extra file ? What should i obverse ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in how games such as Quake 3 were built.

The game is made in such a way that the single player game is in fact a server that starts locally, with a client that connect to it.

This has the advantage that the multiplayer comes for free.

So if you intend to have your game available as 'public' *and* 'local' multi-player, I suggest you make the server part of the game, without having another thing to download for your players.

Comment: Well that was a fast answer thanks for that :) it sounds logical yes, i give it a try ^^ thx again